# using sprite object classes from different files pygame

Tags: python, file, class, pygame

Trying to import a class from a different python file into a main python file. I want to import a class for a boss into the python file with the main game. The file containing the boss' class is called bosscode.py and the main game is called shmup.py.

Right now, bosscode.py looks like this

```
import pygame
from shmup import *

class Boss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  #creates the boss class as a sprite object
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 70))
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect.y = WIDTH / 2  
        self.rect.y = 80
```

I tried importing this file into the main file by saying

```
from bosscode import *

boss = Boss()
```

but it comes up with an error saying

```
NameError: name 'Boss' is not defined
```

Not sure what to do on this. I've tried saying 
`import bosscode` and `from bosscode import boss` but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

so it turns out I was just stupid and forgot to define a rect for the Boss class. After I added `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` into the boss class, it worked perfectly. I didn't even need `from shmup import *` line in bosscode.py